# wp pagenavi for pagination ,too many pages for number of posts 

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

is it possible to have wp-pagenavi set up so that the number of numbers in the pagination is relative to the number of posts.

At the moment , even there is only 3 or 4 posts in a category it still gives me the option to go to lots of old pages , which obviously just show up empty.

Here is an example, there are only 4 posts in this category...
http://limerickfc.hailstormcommerce.com/cms/?page_id=2466

Here is the code Im using for the loop.

```
<?php 
             $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
             query_posts("posts_per_page=12&paged=$paged");

             $archive_query = new WP_Query('cat=14&showposts=12&paged=' . $paged);
             ...
             if (have_posts()) : 
             while ($archive_query->have_posts()) : $archive_query->the_post(); 

                        ...do stuff
  ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

               <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how I would use WP-Pagenavi, you don't need to include the pagination part of the custom query, I think that is the source of your problem.

```
$archive_query = new WP_Query('cat=14&showposts=12');
```

Incidentally, showposts has been deprecated in favour or `posts_per_page`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I may have a solution but I just need to fix something else to do with it first before posting.

Answer (score 0):

My solution...

```
<?php 
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
              ?>

            <?php query_posts('cat=14&posts_per_page=3'."&paged=$paged"); ?>
            <?php
            $id = get_the_ID();
            $count = 0;
             if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

........


            <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query();?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```